# Php script is running on one machine and not on another

Tags: php

I have an automated process to run a php script on 2 machines. It does the following:

```
/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php myphp.php
```

However, It is not running on Host 1(error: /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php: not found) but running fine on Host 2:

**Host 1:** Not running

PHP 7.2.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2018 09:19:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

**Host 2:** running fine

PHP 5.4.40 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2016 07:31:37)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php--->>> This path does not exist on host 1

SELinux is disabled on both hosts.

Comment: `error: /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php: not found` seems like an obvious error to me, thats simply not the path to php on that server

Comment: Yeah, but its not a path that was created automatically during installation. It should have been auto created right? Is the issue because of the version differences?

Comment: should it? how would we know how *your* servers were set up?

Comment: Why would you assume php 7.2 to reside in the php54 folder to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

The path `\opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php` does not seem to be correct. Find out the correct path for the php installation directory.

You can use `which php` or `whereis php` command.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not be installed to the path u are using. Try to use php myphp.php instead.

Comment: I get the below error even on the host on which it was running fine:

php: Command not found.

Comment: The reason is that php is not added to the $PATH variable. How did u install php on host 1?

Comment: I didn't install it. Someone from Unix team did from my organization.